# Spring, background execution or on demand

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I have a spring application that uses `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean` to schedule execution of a method on a regular basis.

Sometimes, I want to call the same method "on demand". It will be trigger by an action on the GUI. Since the method that I want to execute takes a couple of sec, I don't want to block the user GUI until the execution finish. Moreover, I want to coordinate the "on demand" execution with the background thread (mutually exclusive).

Here's one approach:

1. Create a Bean called Manager that
   use a TaskExecutor to schedule a
   Task. The Manager has a method
   Manager.scheduleTask()
2. Both the
   background and the "on demand"
   threads will call the same method on
   the Manager (Manager.scheduleTask)
3. The task runs in a synchronize
   method to assure that only one task
   is running.

I'm looking for more clever/cleaner solutions.

Comment: Are you attached to quartz, or would you consider ditching it for something simpler?

Comment: I'm not attached to quartz. I'm just using it because is easy to integrate with Spring. Do you have any ideas without using quartz ?

Answer (score 4):

If you use Spring 3.0 or newer have a look at the [Task Execution and Scheduling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#scheduling) section of the reference doc.

It shows that there are two annotations:

- `@Scheduled`
- `@Timer`

The solution would be the same at least: having 3 methods:

```
private void  doIt() {...}

@Scheduled(cron="0 0 0 * * MON-FRI")
public void doItEveryDay() {doIt();}

@Async
public void doItOnDemand() {doIt();}
```

But with these annotations, it would be easy to read and easy to understand why there are three methods.

Comment: Tks for the suggestion. Although it still the same solution, I agree that it is easier to read with annotations.

Comment: @Jahan thanks for fixing the typos, but do not modify the content of the answer: it works with Spring 3.0 or newer, Spring 5.3 is not needed!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`SingleThreadExecutor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29).

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
exec.submit(<task>);
```

When your quartz job fires it can submit a task to the executor. Similarly, when your job is run manually, it can also submit a task to the executor. Since the ExecutorService only has a single thread, the task can only run once at a time. The other instance of the task will be queued up until the one which is currently running completes. You don't need to worry about manual synchronisation in this case.

Comment: this will solve the synch stuff. However, It is almost the same solution that I proposed. I´m wondering if there are other -possible better - approaches